# Button's OnClick event firing on initialization?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons, both of which trigger a function to run when clicked, but with different parameters. They should only trigger that function when they are clicked while a specific element on the page exists.

JS code:

```
if (pageExists != null) {

  document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function(53);
  document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(23);
}
```

Button html (They are identical copies other than ID):

```
    <a href="nextpage.html"><button type="button" id="button1">click here</button></a>
```

The function it calls stores that parameter in LocalStorage, and then it should go to the next page using html code. Using breakpoints shows that it stores 53, then 23, as soon as the page loads. The capitalization and ID's are correct.

What can I do to make it wait until one of the two buttons are clicked before executing the function? I can't use jquery for this.

Comment: did you try `addEventListener`? and why are you using `keyword` as function name?

Comment: 53 is the parameter, the function's name is StoreRef, but I figured it wasn't relevant to the question so I just made it function to help people understand what was going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the function instead of setting the function to be called, so when your code is run to set up the event handlers, they run `function(53)` and then set the handler to the return value of that function call, which is invalid. Instead, you want to set it to a function. Try this:

```
if (pageExists != null) {
  document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function.bind(53);
  document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function.bind(23);
}
```

If you can't use `.bind` due to compatibility reasons (this will also explain it better):

```
if (pageExists != null) {
  document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
    function(53);
  };
  document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function() {
    function(23);
  };
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that your function isn't actually called `function`, as that's a reserved keyword.

Comment: `function(53)` ? Won't it shout in console ?

Comment: I can't execute this because I don't actually have the function (or the buttons, or the variable `pageExists`, etc...) If you're talking about `function` being a reserved keyword, it's because OP has renamed the function (I presume, otherwise their code wouldn't have worked) and it's just a placeholder. Also, I meant clarify what `shout in console` means. Throw an error? Output some text? `console` becomes alive and shouts at me through my speakers?

Comment: Yes! It is already alive.. And it will _"shouts at you through my speakers"_

Comment: I see it now, normally I'll call it without the brackets, but I was trying not to duplicate code by reusing a function. I can't seem to get .bind to work for me though, it stores '[object MouseEvent]' instead of either 53 or 23.

And yeah, the function is called StoreRef, I figured using general terms would make it easier to read if anyone else had the same issue.